# JSON duplicate data in youtube-data-api

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was running youtube api on channels and for certain channels (an example given below), I got duplicate JSON data under localizations. For e.g.,

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?id=UCbbVAtyywkQscZc76qc8L5Q&part=brandingSettings,contentDetails,contentOwnerDetails,id,snippet,statistics,status,topicDetails,localizations&key=...
```

I get this under localizations

```
"localizations": {
    "de": {
     "title": "Ruesch Productions Aviation Cinematography",
     "description": "Welcome to the official RUESCH PRODUCTIONS YouTube Channel! Experience, aircrafts and the exciting life of airports as you have never seen before. We guarantee you a lot of emotions in our films, with exciting music and spectacular views. Feel the fascination of flying! \n\nThis is aviation cinematography! \n\nYour Producer\nAndy Ruesch"
    },
    "de": {
     "title": "Ruesch Productions Aviation Cinematography",
     "description": "Willkommen auf dem offiziellen RUESCH PRODUCTIONS YouTube-Kanal! Wir sind Ihr Spezialist für die Luftfahrtdreharbeiten , und vieles mehr. Erleben Sie Flugzeuge und das aufregende Leben auf den Flughäfen, wie Sie es noch nie gesehen haben. Wir garantieren Ihnen eine Menge Emotionen in unseren Filmen, mit aufregender Musik und spektakulären Ausblicke. Spüren Sie die Faszination des Fliegens! Wir sind Ihr Spezialist für Aerial-, Cockpit- und Airportshots.\n\nDas ist aviation cinematography!\n\nIhr Produzent\nAndy Ruesch"
    }
   }
```

As you can see "de" appears twice in the JSON array. Why is this happening?

Comment: someone added it twice?

Comment: I think it was added twice for two separate languages. But the language identifiers are not proper (showing the same language twice).